# how to get previous value of textbox in jquery on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 $(".whitebox").on('change', function () {
       var previousAmt = $(this).data("old"); //  i want previous value
        var id = this.id;
        var slpitid = id.split("_");

        var checkboxid = "#chck_" + slpitid[0];
        if ($(checkboxid).is(':checked')) {
            var tipFlag = true;
        }
        else {
            var tipFlag = false;
        }

        if (tipFlag === true)
        {
            $("#amounttipchange").modal('show');
        }
        //alert(previousAmount);
    });
```

i want to store previous value on change event how can i perform in jquery  i am not able to store value using $(this).data("old"); any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please add your `HTML` code too

Comment: `i am not able to store value using $(this).data("old")` -- why?

Comment: previousAmt  =$(this).data("old") output is emtpty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got this right, but you forgot to update the `data-old` in your code, below is an example and [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jasaqiwuwo/edit?js,console)

```
 $(".whitebox").on('change', function (event) {
   // on first change will be empty string
   // as no previous value was set
   var oldValue = event.target.dataset.old;
   console.log('old value', oldValue);

   // your code here

   // at the end assign new value to data-old attribute
   $(this).data('old', event.target.value);
   console.log(event.target.value);
 });
```

http://jsbin.com/jasaqiwuwo/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var prevVal = $('input').val(); //init val
var valuesHistory = [prevVal]; 
$('input').data('prevData', prevVal);

$('input').on('change', function() {
  console.log('prev value from data: ', $(this).data('prevData'));
  console.log('prev value from var: ', prevVal);
  console.log('log: ', valuesHistory);
  valuesHistory.push($('input').val());
  $('input').data('prevData', $('input').val());
  prevVal = $(this).val();
});
// you can also get the prev value, like that valuesHistory[valuesHistory.length-2];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#checkboxid").on('click',function(){
   $(this).data('old',$(this).val());
});
```

And then use your change event.